# "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console"

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-client, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I have linked my project in the Developer Console and I have looked up various sources to find a solution to this problem. What I am actually trying to do is use the inappproducts REST resource to fetch all my products from Play Console using the get() method. A lot of suggestions that I read was to add a new in-app product which I tried doing but the error still persists after adding new products, editing existing products, adding new subscriptions, etc. I can also see that the Google Play Developer API has been enabled for this project as well. I have also created credentials for both oauth and service account. I have been trying to call this API from the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) using my Developers account and since I am the owner of this account, I believe it should work. What should I do?